# Can assignment to auto have a type other than the result of the r-value expression?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17, c++20, conversion-operator

Consider the following:

```
auto tmp = a + b;
```

Where `a` and `b` are user defined types which returns a proxy object to delay evaluation (this is required for more complex expressions than shown).

Is there a way that the result in this case be something other the result type of the operator overload?

I am wondering if perhaps an implicit conversion operator with the r/l-value specifier `T operator() &&` might be of use here, but I can't quite think how.

I appreciate this question is vague and lacks details, but I think what I want conceptually very simple.

I can think of a way to do this if I didn't want to do `auto tmp = ...` but rather `some_concrete_type tmp = ...` but consuming the proxy in the constructor.

Comment: So normally `a + b` will delay evaluation, but now you want it to not delay and evaluate the value straight away of type `T`? Seems inconsistent to expect `operator+` to behave differently without being told to. Maybe some more details on how/why the delayed evaluation is there and when it's supposed to kick in would help clarify the problem.

Comment: @super the case I have written out is trivial, but I if I can chain together multiple operators then I can apply some pretty significant optimisations. so `auto tmp = a + b + c;` using then proxies might be considerable faster in my use case than `auto tmp0 = a+ b; auto tmp1 = tmp0 + c;`

Comment: `auto tmp = a + b + c;` is set the type of `tmp` to whatever the final result of the full expression is, which will be whatever type `+ c` returns.

Comment: People have proposed an `operator auto` to apply in cases like this so as to produce a “real” (rather than “delayed”) value, but it’s not yet gone anywhere.

Comment: Specifically, [P0672 Implicit Evaluation of "auto" Variables](http://wg21.link/P0672). Last seen at Toronto (2017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is always going to deduce its type from the initializer.  It is not going to apply a conversion unless you do so yourself (besides the fact that it removes top level reference and *cv* qualifications).

If your initialization expression results in some proxy instead of a concrete type, then that is what `auto` will be deduced to.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, is there a way I make the above expression illegal and therefore force the user to type out the evaluated (non-proxy) type (which would take the proxy as an implicit ctor).

Comment: @111111 You could make the constructors of the proxy type protected or private and give friend access to the concrete types.  That would let you create objects of the proxy type in the concrete type functions but won't let you create an instance outside of the concrete class functions.

Comment: seems reasonable. I am going to wait and see if anyone else has any other suggestions but if not after a bit I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @111111 My suggestion might not work 100% for you.  With C++17 guaranteed copy elision it is still possible to construct an object that has private constructors in non-friend code :(.  See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f14d394b6f4e778b

Comment: @NathanOliver seems reasonable -- NoCreate specifically designates Create as a factory for it via the friend declaration

Comment: @NathanOliver so I mocked up what I wanted here, and bizarrely where I'd expect auto to trigger an compile error (because `proxy` is not replaceable) it actually seems to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17687b8ebba17788   - I am guessing this has something to do with copy elision constructing the result inplace.

Comment: @111111 That is correct.  It's actually `operator+` that is constructing the object, so the elision takes place and "all is good".  Not sure how to stop that.  You could ask a Q about that.